# How to pass on argparse argument to function as kwargs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments, argparse

I have a class defined as follows

```
class M(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...do_something
```

and I have the result of `argparse.parse_args()`, for example:

```
> args = parse_args()
> print args
Namespace(value=5, message='test', message_type='email', extra="blah", param="whatever")
```

I want to pass on the values of this namespace (except `message_type`) to create an instance of the class `M`. I have tried

```
M(args)
```

but got an error

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

which I do not understand. How can I

1. remove the value `message_type` from the list in `args`
2. pass on the values as if I would type `M(value=5, message='test', extra="blah", param="whatever")` directly.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need to pass in the result of `vars(args)` instead:

```
M(**vars(args))
```

The [`vars()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) returns the namespace of the Namespace instance (its `__dict__` attribute) as a dictionary.

Inside `M.__init__()`, simply ignore the `message_type` key.

Comment: Thats exactly what I need. Thanks. Except for removal of the certain key. I need it to be removed, I cannot just ignore it for reasons outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I suggest to do `arg_dict = dict((k,v) for k,v in vars(args).items() if k!="message_type")` to avoid possible undefined behaviour with `vars`.

Comment: @Alex: what undefined behaviour with `vars`? You can filter out the `message_type` key that way, sure, but do that for it's own sake, not because `vars()` might have undefined behaviour (which it doesn't).

Comment: @Alex: I'd rather make the `M` class more robust in the face of extra keyword arguments it doesn't support.

Comment: Note
From the documentation of vars: 
`The returned dictionary should not be modified: the effects on the corresponding symbol table are undefined. [2]`. As for your suggestion, `M` can be one of many classes absolutely detached from what I am doing here. These classes cannot possibly know of some abundant keyword (and might give an error otherwise). Let's say, those classes cannot be modified.

Comment: @Alex: The values are *copied* into the `M.__init__` parameters, so the original mapping is never modified. If you need to regulate what keywords are passed in, use a whitelist instead.